# Pig Script throws Out Of Memory Exception on Tez, but works with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hcatalog, apache-tez

Pig(with Tez execution engine) script shown below throws Out Of Memory Exception, with a 15GB employee table on a 4 node cluster.
**It works fine when the execution engine is changed to MapReduce.**

```
pig -F -x tez -useHCatalog<<EOF
EMP_TMP = LOAD 'employee' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
EMP = foreach EMP_TMP generate emp_id, log_time , dept_id, 10 as emp_type;
EMP_VALID =  filter EMP by (ToDate(ToString(log_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') >= ToDate('2015-09-01','yyyy-MM-dd') and ToDate(ToString(log_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') <= ToDate('2015-09-30','yyyy-MM-dd'));
STORE EMP_VALID INTO 'EMP_VALID' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
EOF
```

Error message is,

```
2015-11-13 11:34:06,113 [PigTezLauncher-0] INFO  org.apache.tez.client.TezClient - Submitting dag to TezSession, sessionName=PigLatin:DefaultJobName, applicationId=application_1447412577542_0027, dagName=PigLatin:DefaultJobName-0_scope-0
grunt> 2015-11-13 11:34:07,953 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 6016: Out of memory.
```

The table size is too small compared to the cluster memory and storage.
Is there any memory parameter in Tez which needs a particular configuration?

Comment: have you tried increasing the memory?

e.g. SET mapred.child.java.opts '-Xmx4096M'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by increasing the pig heap size, whose default value is very small in pig.

```
export PIG_HEAPSIZE=8192
```